# Min and max for each row with dataframe in R

Tags: r, date, max, min

I need to calculate the processing time for several people who have taken an online test. So for each person there are numerous timestamps (one timestamp per task). The duration of the processing is calculated from the time difference between the smallest and the largest date value. The following example works (student_1), but it only works if no value is missing (student_2 and student_3). Are there any ideas?

```
library(anytime)

number <- c(1, 2, 3)
uniquename <- c("student_1", "student_2",  "student_3")
timestamp_1 <- c(anytime("2020-02-25T12:42:56.476Z"),NA,anytime("2020-02-25T10:05:22.388Z"))
timestamp_2 <- c(anytime("2020-02-25T12:51:22.388Z"),anytime("2020-02-25T12:51:22.388Z"),NA)
timestamp_3 <- c(anytime("2020-02-25T13:00:45.042Z"),anytime("2020-02-25T13:00:45.042Z"),NA)
timestamp_4 <- c(anytime("2020-02-25T13:31:48.073Z"),anytime("2020-02-25T13:31:48.073Z"),NA)
timestamp_5 <- c(anytime("2020-02-25T14:22:57.103Z"),anytime("2020-02-25T15:00:00Z"),anytime("2020-02-25T14:05:00Z"))

df3 <- data.frame(number,
                  uniquename,
                  timestamp_1,
                  timestamp_2,
                  timestamp_3,
                  timestamp_4,
                  timestamp_5)

df3$date_min <- apply(df3[3:7], 1, FUN=min)
df3$date_max <- apply(df3[3:7], 1, FUN=max)

df3$date_min <- anytime(df3$date_min)
df3$date_max <- anytime(df3$date_max)

df3$diff <- difftime(df3$date_min, df3$date_max, units = "mins")
df3$diff <- round(df3$diff,0)
df3$diff <- as.numeric(df3$diff)*(-1)

View(df3)
```

Answer (score 1):

here is a `data.table` approach

```
library( data.table )
setDT(df3)
#get columns with timestamps
cols = grep( "^timestamp_", names(df3), value = TRUE )
#check if at least two timestampa are given, then calculate min and max
df3[ df3[, rowSums( !is.na(.SD) ), .SDcols = cols ] >= 2, 
     date_min := do.call( pmin, c( .SD, list( na.rm = TRUE ) ) ), .SDcols = cols ]
df3[ df3[, rowSums( !is.na(.SD) ), .SDcols = cols ] >= 2, 
     date_max := do.call( pmax, c( .SD, list( na.rm = TRUE ) ) ), .SDcols = cols ]

#    number uniquename         timestamp_1         timestamp_2
# 1:      1  student_1 2020-02-25 12:42:56 2020-02-25 12:51:22
# 2:      2  student_2                <NA> 2020-02-25 12:51:22
# 3:      3  student_3 2020-02-25 10:05:22                <NA>
#            timestamp_3         timestamp_4         timestamp_5
# 1: 2020-02-25 13:00:45 2020-02-25 13:31:48 2020-02-25 14:22:57
# 2: 2020-02-25 13:00:45 2020-02-25 13:31:48 2020-02-25 15:00:00
# 3:                <NA>                <NA> 2020-02-25 14:05:00
#               date_min            date_max
# 1: 2020-02-25 12:42:56 2020-02-25 14:22:57
# 2: 2020-02-25 12:51:22 2020-02-25 15:00:00
# 3: 2020-02-25 10:05:22 2020-02-25 14:05:00
```

Comment: updated with check for at least two different timestamps on each row

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, you can just add the `na.rm` argument for `min()` and `max()` with your current approach:

```
df3$date_min <- apply(df3[3:7], 1, min, na.rm = TRUE)
df3$date_max <- apply(df3[3:7], 1, max, na.rm = TRUE)

df3[c("number", "uniquename", "date_min", "date_max")]
  number uniquename            date_min            date_max
1      1  student_1 2020-02-25 12:42:56 2020-02-25 14:22:57
2      2  student_2 2020-02-25 12:51:22 2020-02-25 15:00:00
3      3  student_3 2020-02-25 10:05:22 2020-02-25 14:05:00
```

Comment: 'na.rm = TRUE ' was the missing option. Now all timestamps are considered and missing values are ignored.Thanks.